# How to add fill in a \pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-pic

I wrote a TikZ `pic` for a simple database icon (first picture below). What I want is to hide the two edges that are behind overlaying boxes, similar to the second picture. I thought I could add a white fill to the boxes, but how do I do that?

[image]
[image]

P.S.: this code is quite ugly and repetitive, feedback is always welcome.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    db/.pic={
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0   ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0   );
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0   ) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] ( 0.3,0   ) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.2 ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0.2 );
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.2 ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend left=90]  (0.3,0.2 );

        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.25) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0.25);
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.25) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] ( 0.3,0.25) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.45) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0.45);
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.45) edge[looseness=0.5,bend left=90]  (0.3,0.45);

        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.5 ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0.5 );
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.5 ) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] ( 0.3,0.5 ) -- ++(0,0.2);
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.7 ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend right=90] (0.3,0.7 );
        \draw[-,pic actions] (-0.3,0.7 ) edge[looseness=0.5,bend left=90]  (0.3,0.7 );
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {db};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code is "repetitive" that's a good indication that you should be using `\foreach` somewhere: the three circles are essentially the same, so you only need to write them once if you use a `\foreach` statement. This also makes the code clearer and easier to modify.

In terms of adding `fill=white` the reason why this does not work with the code in the question is that there is nothing to fill: you need to have a circular path. Naively, you could just splice some of your draw statements together, however, this won't work either because drawing with an `edge` does not change the "current coordinate" of the path, so you won't get a circuit. One way to get around this is to use `to` instead. Once you have done this then you can add `fill=white` to get what you want, namely:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    db/.pic={
        \foreach \y in {0,0.25,0.5} {
        \draw[fill=white](-0.3,\y) to [looseness=0.5,bend right=90]   ++(0.6,0)
                   -- ++(0,0.2) to [green,looseness=0.5,bend left=90] ++(-0.6,0)
                   -- ++(0,-0.2);
        \draw(-0.3,\y+0.2) edge[looseness=0.5,bend left=90] ++(0.6,0);
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {db};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```